# How to avoid drilling into the drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drill

I want to drill a tiny hole from the bathroom into the next room. This wall has a sink and shower attached. On the other wall of the bathroom is a toilet and bath tub. Above the bathroom is another flat, which I assume has the same layout as mine. So above should be a bathroom as well (which I can acoustically confirm). I guess I share the drain with the above flat, which means my target wall most likely contains a drain going vertically from top to bottom, unless there's only one drain for the bathroom and it's on the toilet side. I guess this drawing makes the layout more clear:

[image]

I have [this scanner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004TACMZ8) to find electricity and water pipes, but drains are non metallic. How can I make sure not to hit the drain? The flat is in Germany.

The wall is most likely a brick wall. That's at least what I found in the kitchen. I didn't drill anything there yet, so I don't know the dust color. But the wall doesn't sound  hollow.

Comment: It would help to know why you want to do this. You're asking how to perform a specific solution, but if we know the problem, we might be able to find a better solution entirely. That aside, why not drill from the bathroom side?

Comment: I would drill from the bathroom side. I just painted it on the other room to make clear that the hole could be anywhere on that wall. I need that hole to put a wire between those two rooms.

Comment: Again, *why* do you need to put a wire between the two rooms? It would really help to know what you hope to accomplish. Also, if you drill from the bathroom side, you should have some idea where the drain is, given you know the sink location.

Comment: I need a LAN connection between those two rooms. Wireless is no option. Well, I know where the sink is and I know where the shower is. Other than that I have no idea how this is layed out inside of the wall. My best guess would be it's between both of them. But that's only me guessing. I'm asking here for a more reliable method.

Comment: Sorry, you still don't seem to be understanding me. I'm asking why you need a LAN connection to the bathroom. Are you installing networked speakers? Do you want a smart TV? Do you just want to surf the web with ridiculous throughput to pass the time?

Comment: Part of why I am trying to get more information is that it may change how we view the question. It can change where you will want to drill the hole. As of now, it seems like you could place the hole anywhere and the odds are good that a random spot won't have something in the way. If you really don't want to provide more info, I'd recommend finding a stud, drilling a 1/4" (6mm) hole through the *center* of the stud, passing unterminated Cat cable through, then adding an RJ-45 termination on the inside. If the drain goes through a stud, there *should* be a metal plate protecting it.

Comment: Exactly, the hole can be anywhere on that wall. The only hard requirement is connecting those two rooms with a wire. It's a soft requirement to do that through that wall, as an option I could also go through another wall and lay the wire around corners and even more walls, but I don't see how this should be benefical. Why the connection: The bathroom contains my self built radio beam internet router, which cannot handle too many wifi connections and no other place suits for the uplink. I need to attach other devices via cable.

Comment: Can the router be moved to another location (for example, above the door), or to a wall that is unlikely to contain drains?

Comment: I was all set to type up an answer, but the brick wall part threw me off. Please add as many details as you can. The more info you provide, the better.

Comment: Yeah, Sorry about the brick wall. I just realized it the moment I saw your stud advice. Ok, I'm not 100% sure about the brick wall. But knocking sounds quiet solid. Tomorrow I can make a small test drill and examine the dust. Regarding the router location, I could theoretically lay a cable outside on the wall through the bathroom to any other wall, e.g. above the door. But I would prefer to go the direct way, as it really is only a 15cm drill. And actually even if I would hit the drain, it's not the end of the world, as this would be covered by insurance. But it's an avoidable annoyance.

Comment: Aren't there construction records in Germany? Or are fine details just not put in construction permit documents? Aren't there people who know the normal routing of water and drain pipes in the type of building you are in?